# windows 2003 server login script to Sync Folder

Tags: windows-server-2003, folder-redirection

in windows 2003 server we have built in option to SYNC my documents, desktop, application data ... folders from client computers to server.

i am looking for some login script to to SYNC one special folder/Folders from Client computer to Server.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to just sync that folder at login? or did you want it to live sync throughout the day?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try using the resource kit command Robocopy, which will sync two directories via the command line, so can be used in a login script. Eg

```
robocopy.exe "c:\client_directory" "f:\server_directory" /mir
```

Answer (score 0):

the "sync" you are referring to, is called "roaming profiles".

A simple script implementation is described below that may copy something and log it.

Modify the following to your needs (very basic)

```
REM: Login Script for XYZ
XCOPY /Y /E %SYSTEMROOT%\SourceFolder \\myfileserver\hiddenshare$\%USERNAME%\DestFolder
echo %DATE%-%TIME%-%USERNAME% Copied SourceFolder from %COMPUTERNAME% to Server >> \\myfileserver\hiddenshare$\log.txt
```

Then save it somewhere like here: \MyDomain\NETLOGON\logon.bat

The "login script" can be applied via group policy, ie, create a new policy applied to your staff's OU

```
User Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Scripts -> Logon
```

Or, if you just need it for a few, (and you saved it in the NETLOGON folder above) simply edit the user account (Profile Tab -> Logon Script textbox) and enter the filename.

Answer (score 0):

with w2k+ client side cache is another option to sync files, but once again I think its limited to desktop,appdata,mydocs and dang can't remember the other.  Synctoys from ms will work quiet nicely for what your doing also!